# Is it possible to change a karma coverage report title?

Tags: code-coverage, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I'm working on an application who has two sides; a desktop and a mobile. In order to test that everything work's fine, we wrote some unit tests, and setup a karma-coverage.

I already have two config file, the first one is for mobile, the second one for desktop, and it generate two distinct coverage reports.

What I need, is to change the default report title. Actually, this is "Code coverage report for All files". I want to set it up to "Code coverage report for All files - Smartphone|Desktop".

Anyone knows if there is a parameter to change this default title?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey/info)/[Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tampermonkey/info) script for this:

```
 document.querySelector(".entity").innerHTML += " - Smartphone|Desktop"
```

For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Code Coverage
// @namespace   script[id]
// @include     http://127.0.0.1:8080/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelector(".entity").innerHTML += " - Smartphone|Desktop"
```

Then save the page as HTML, MHTML, data URL, or PDF.

**References**

- [Test Cases · greasemonkey/greasemonkey Wiki](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/wiki/Test-Cases)
- [Creating a dismissible banner component with Vanilla JavaScript](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/creating-a-dismissible-banner-component-ad02493b1cc2)